# Resetting TimeSpan.FromMinutes()

Tags: .net, vb.net

I am trying to use a Stopwatch and TimeSpan.

Declaration:

```
Dim swTimer As New Stopwatch
Dim tsCD As TimeSpan
tsCD = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(2)
```

I've successfully created a ".Tick" event on my timer (tmrCountingDown) that counts down like so:

```
Private Sub tmrCountingDown_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles tmrCountingDown.Tick
    Dim SamplesTS As TimeSpan = tsCD - swTimer.Elapsed
    btnDisplay.Text = String.Format("{0}{1}:{2:00}", SamplesTS.Hours, SamplesTS.Minutes, SamplesTS.Seconds)
End Sub
```

This lets me successfully countdown and display the minutes and seconds on my button "btnDisplay".

**Side Question: Currently that line of code displays the format 00:00. Is there a way to change this to simply 0:00? Where the first set are minutes (single digit) and the second set are seconds (double digit?)**



Now the main issue that I am having. When I click on the button, it is supposed to change the .FromMinutes(2) to .FromMinutes(2.5) and refresh the countdown while ***not resetting the stopwatch (I need the maintain the elapsed time)*** like so:

```
Private Sub btnDisplay_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnDisplay.Click
    Counter += 1 'Just an integer counter that I have
    tsCD = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(2.5)
End Sub
```

The first time that I click btnDisplay, it doesn't do what it is supposed to: reset the entire countdown and start from 2:30. It instead seems to just add 30 seconds. When I click it a second time, it doesn't even do anything.

**Question: How do I refresh the TimeSpan countdown on each button click to 2.5 seconds without resetting the otherwise messing with the actual stopwatch and timer?**

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Your current format is somewhat confusing anyway - both "1 hour and 0 minutes" and "10 minutes" are represented as "10:00". Is there any reason you're not using another colon for clarity? I would actually suggest asking the formatting side as an entirely separate question - Stack Overflow works best when each post is a single, well-specified question.

Comment: Sure it adds 30 seconds - you change tsCD by 30 seconds from 2 minutes to 2.5 minutes. Afterwars there's no change anymore (2.5 stays 2.5). You really should reset the stopwatch. You may save the elapsed time at this point somewhere.

Comment: @JonSkeet Hey - I actually tried to do some Googling on this and couldn't figure it out. I'll post the formatting issue as a different question :) Thanks!

Comment: Or use a seperate counter that you reset each time to an appropriate value.

Comment: @JeffRSon Well, the issue I'm having is that I have another button that displays the elapsed time and I need it to remain uninterrupted and I'm just not sure how I would accomplish that :(

Comment: If you want the elapsed time to stay the same, then you should probably be resetting `tsCD` to `swTimer.Elapsed + TimeSpan.FromMinutes(2.5)`. After all, you want the total time to be "however long it's already been, plus another 2.5 minutes". This is where it's important to be really precise about the meaning of variables - I suspect if you tried to document `tsCD` in detail (and ideally give it a clearer name) you'd work out what to do more quickly.

Comment: @JonSkeet Wow, thank you! That worked beautifully. Would you mind putting that into an answer so I can mark it as such pretty please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think of it this way:

- You have a "time elapsed" that you don't want to change
- You want to reset the "time remaining" so that it's 2.5 minutes
- You're currently *computing* the time remaining based with the formula of "total time - time elapsed"

If you combine all of those together, that means when you press the button, you want to change the "total time" to "current time elapsed + 2.5 minutes". In other words:

```
tsCD = swTimer.Elapsed + TimeSpan.FromMinutes(2.5)
```

As a meta note, I would encourage you to use really clear, descriptive names - ideally without the type-specifying prefixes unless they're genuinely useful (which I don't think they are here). If you'd given the `TimeSpan` the name `totalCountdownTime` or something similar, I suspect you'd have worked this out already. And of course when names can't convey everything, you can add more details in an XML comment :)

Comment: @jasonmills There are two people that know all about time One is called John Skeet and the other is his apprentice and he's called The Doctor.